# For each string assign an integer and put it into a list

Tags: python

I have a ticket and each ticket will be a color. I put the colors into a string.

```
 ticket = "gray", "orange", "pink"
```

The goal is to assign each string to a corresponding number and put it into a list.
I know I can use dictionary:

```
 mydict = {"gray": 1, "orange": 2, "pink": 3}

 num_of_queen = mydict["queen"]
```

My question is how to assign the corresponding numbers without using dictionary and to put it into a list?

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If this is homework, read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of dictionaries, e.g.:

```
l = [{"id":"1","color":"gray"}, {"id":"2","color":"orange"}, {"id":"3","color":"pink"}]
```